# tpl and update method in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In my app I am using tpl but its not working: can any one tell me what to do and where I am wrong?

Inside config :

```
{
    id: 'content',
    tpl: "<div class='attorney-details'>hi:{details}</div>"
},
```

and my Update method is :

```
update: function(newRecord) {
    if (newRecord) {
        currentView=this.getRecord().data;
        this.down('#content').setData(newRecord.data);
    }
}
```

At output not even `"Hi"` is printed.
Also, if an alert is added in the update method it is not executed.
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of component is that? (It depends on the parent's configuration). What component is your `update` method attached to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step would be to make sure your update method would be executed. Not really enough info to figure out what is going on with your code. It looks like your update method is located inside your view with your reference to this.down, so you need to make sure the component you are using has access to a store. If you don't you can just pass an object to update the template like this http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/7mAmV/.